# Swipe.js not working in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am building just a page with an image slider. I have tested the JS and HTML in a previous project, not I just need it to work on Meteor.

I added jQuery with `mrt add jquery` and then added the other javascript files into a folder I created at `client/lib` . But Now I am getting this error

```
ReferenceError: Swipe is not defined
```

[image: console]

here is my template

```
<template name="imageSlider">
  <h1>Cases</h1>
  <div class="casesContainer">

    <div class="caseTitle">
      <span class="caseNumber">Case</span>
      <div class="wrap">
        <span class="caseBack" onclick='mySwipe.prev()'>Back</span>
        <span class="caseForward" onclick='mySwipe.next()'>Forward</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id='caseSlider' style='max-width:500px;margin:0 auto' class='swipe'>
      <div class='swipe-wrap'>
      <div><b>0</b></div>
      <div><b>1</b></div>
      <div><b>2</b></div>
      <div><b>3</b></div>
      <div><b>4</b></div>
      <div><b>5</b></div>
    </div>
  </div>        
</template>
```

Here is my `swipe-init.js`

```
var elem = document.getElementById('caseSlider');
window.caseSlider = Swipe(elem, {
  startSlide: 1,
  speed: 400,
  auto: 3000,
  continuous: true,
  disableScroll: false,
  stopPropagation: false,
  callback: function(index, elem) {},
  transitionEnd: function(index, elem) {}
});
```

Comment: The error is probably in your swipe-init.js file. If I had to guess it'd be a namespacing issue http://docs.meteor.com/#namespacing

Answer (score 1):

As [emgee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/542734/emgee) mentioned in the comments it looks like a namespacing issue.

After pulling up the [swipe.js](https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe/blob/master/swipe.js) file and taking a look it appears to be exactly that.

If you look at the function:

```
function Swipe(container, options) {

  "use strict";

  // utilities
  var noop = function() {}; // simple no operation function
  var offloadFn = function(fn) { setTimeout(fn || noop, 0) }; // offload a functions execution

  // chec...
```

You will see that it is not in the global scope. In meteor when you define a function using the function keyword, it is only accessible within that file. To make it global you should change it to:

```
Swipe = function(container, options) {

  "use strict";

  // utilities
  var noop = function() {}; // simple no operation function
  var offloadFn = function(fn) { setTimeout(fn || noop, 0) }; // offload a functions execution

  // chec...
```

Comment: I made the change to the file as you mentioned. But stil getting an error. The console said that it was because of this line `window.caseSlider = Swipe(elem, {` in my swipe-init.js